# Output in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Been writing code in Javascript for a couple of months, but always inside pages such as CodeAcademy or Udacity, with their own command line.

And now trying my code directly on a text editor I have a very main question. Why does the text in console.log don't show up in the browswer? I'm attaching here a very basic example to see if I'm doing something wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

    <title>Triangles</title>
    <meta = charset=utf-8>

</head>

<body>

    <script>

        var titulo = "w3resource";


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Appreciate it! Thanks,

Jaime

Comment: I can't see any to call of console.log

Answer (score 1):

You need to first print to the console using

```
console.log(titulo);
```

Then, open the console/developers-tools of your browser to see all outputs

```
Chrome: Wrench Menu > Tools > JavaScript Console

FireFox: Tools > Web Developer > Web Console
```

Comment: or just press F12 (in chrome) :)

Comment: @RobinHellemans F12 only works in windows.  For chrome on mac, it's `command-option-I`, ditto for Firefox on mac

Answer (score 0):

you are only declaring variable, try logging your variable using console.log

try this

```
console.log(titulo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show the console. F12 to show developer tools then choose console to see your output with a call to console.log.

There are also other uses/calls for console - see chrome api here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api